# Sencha Touch2: cannot Parse Json file inside store

Tags: json, sencha-touch-2

I am new to Sencha Touch2. am facing problem while loading nested data from Json file.
This is my json file:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [
      "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.yellowpages.com.au/\"\u003eYellow Pages\u003c/a\u003e"
   ],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8711140,
               "lng" : 151.1990420
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/travel_agent-71.png",
         "id" : "ddd678ac0a16d83fdc25500ccb3d6aa27b7f5548",
         "name" : "Darling Harbour",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1088,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://plus.google.com/117001986278088134060\"\u003eStephen SteveT\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRiAAAAyl02-KJEBTh19Pc4YuOhMn0DPYLCat_1HMSwX_icBwgyjWr7QGkT262oE57hMlOUypibloD1oFwxBJ8Iq3oJCLKBNXcyAmw7000P91LblItAcxuVyvltfRggSLwT36pooEmZiKITyEuwAmpKpGrxhRIQhyMbZ-cHFI6zSayNRRiH_BoUgWH-2M6mR1IO9MuftuuYkZRHUZ4",
               "width" : 1600
            }
         ],
         "rating" : 4.30,
         "reference" : "CnRtAAAAmNBHFs0qF9UJEw1NccjMySkm4aH3cEL6cCkLj-V4rkDJJE81-fFOar6PAtoK5d70GLJTgh_LcpysxH41iRI4hW3YreiPI66GBJYEeWA6SbgNQrJy6RbTw7LbhB6vYb3gfzpV2lE6fUtaIjx3WOLjsBIQVjFdJTUy55L1fzdzyufUaBoU194V7aIidzGbj7aRUaObJdl5GvM",
         "types" : [ "travel_agency", "cafe", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Sydney"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.870540,
               "lng" : 151.1988150
            }
         },.........
```

here am able to get data of icon, id, name. i followed a tutorial. but how can i read data inside 'location' of 'lat' and 'lng'. the below is my store.

```
Ext.define('CustomList.store.StoreList', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    requires:['Ext.data.reader.Json','Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],
    config:{
        model:'CustomList.model.ModelList',
        autoLoad:'true',
        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
       url:'http://localhost:9091/Json/sample.json',

            reader:{
                type:'json',
                rootProperty:'results'
                }
        }
    }
});
```

This is my model:

```
Ext.define('CustomList.model.ModelList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields:['geometry.location.lat','geometry.location.lng']

    }})
```

This is my list:
ShowList.js:

```
Ext.define('CustomList.view.ShowList',{
    extend:'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'showList',
    config:{
        layout:'fit',
        styleHtmlContent:'true',
        styleHtmlCls:'showListCls',
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'list',
                id: 'listitems',
                store:'StoreList',
//                itemTpl:'{id},{name},{vicinity}'
                itemTpl:'{modelList.geometry.location.lat} {modelList.geometry.location.lng}'

               }]


    }
});
```

Can any one please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-rootProperty)

> rootProperty : String The name of the property which contains the
>   Array of row objects. For JSON reader it's dot-separated list of
>   property names.

In your code you're setting the `rootProperty` to `geometry` so I guess the reader is gonna think that all the data is in the first `geometry` attribute.

One solution would be to set your `rootProperty` to `results`, set the `field` config of your model to `fields:['geometry']` and access the `lat` and `lng` like this

```
yourModelInstance.geometry.location.lat;
yourModelInstance.geometry.location.lng;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i have followed as you suggested but am getting error. i have updated the code and added showList.js for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: rootProperty:'results.geometry.location' should be rootProperty:'results' and fields:['lat','lng'] should be fields:['geometry']

Comment: getting 
[Ext.XTemplate#apply] Error: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined . Can you please update the code. Thanks.

Comment: itemTpl should be itemTpl:'{geometry.location.lat} {geometry.location.lng}'

Comment: now getting Error: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined.

Comment: I said it should be fields:['geometry'] and NOT fields:['geometry.location.lat','geometry.location.lng']